# How to average and equally compare categories with different number of data elements?

Tags: average

I am extracting a list of categories that contain a number of listed values.  I am then averaging and doing a compare i.  here is the general explanation.

Example:

- Category 1 has 2 elements
- Category 2 has 5 elements
- Category 3 has 9 elements
- Category 4 has 10 elements
- Category 5 has 17 elements
- Category 6 has 26 elements
- Category 7 has 55 elements

Within each category, there are individual elements that contain a score.  I am attempting to compare the average score for the overall category compared to another category equally.

The problem is that because each category contains a different amount of elements, the average comparison to evaluate is not the same.  For example, comparing Category 1 with 2 elements to a Category 7 with 55 elements.

If Category 1 had 55 elements, then I could say that I am equally comparing the overall value to Category  with 55 elements also.

My first thought was to say that each category must have 10 scores to equally compare.

For Category 1, I thought about just taking the 2 scores, and then add 8 zeros to show that the category is weaker due to not having the rest of the 8, while comparing against Category 7 with it's strongest top 10 scores out of the 52, but I don't believe that will provide any useful result.

The same would apply to Category 2 with 5 elements, that 5 zeros are factored in to make 10.
The same would apply to Category 3 with 9 elements, that 1 zero are factored in to make 10.

What I am trying to do is find a way to compare apples to apples by knowing that each category is compared against a set limit of 10 scores to gauge which is stronger in score relative to the others categories.

Is there a process or method in which I can address this? Is there a better way to approach this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can't decide for you which of the aggregate function is the most appropriate to your case. Usually, people use average or max like :

```
select category, count(1), avg(score), max(score) from scores group by category
```